# What do we call this (new?) higher-order function?

Tags: python, haskell, functional-programming, theory, higher-order-functions

I am trying to name what I think is a new idea for a higher-order function. I want to call it a BinaryProjection, but my compatriot wants to call it the Plow. We tossed around the idea of a Snow Blower for a minute, too. Anyway, to the important part, here is the code in Python and Haskell to demonstrate the concept, which will be explained afterward.

Python:

```
>>> def plow(f, l):
       return map(lambda t: f(*t), zip(l, l[1:]))
>>> plow(operator.add, [0, 1, 2, 3])
[1, 3, 5]
```

Haskell:

```
Prelude> let binaryProjection f xs = zipWith f xs (drop 1 xs)
Prelude> binaryProjection (+) [0,1,2,3]
[1,3,5]
```

As you may be able to infer, the sequence is being iterated through, utilizing adjacent elements as the parameters for the function you pass it, projecting the results into a new sequence. So, has anyone seen the functionality we've created? Is this familiar at all to those in the functional community? If not, what do we name it?

```
---- Update ----
```

There are three candidates for the name. **meld**, **pinch**, and **pleat**. In Haskell, they would be implemented as so (using "meld"):

```
Prelude> let meld xs = zip xs (drop 1 xs)
Prelude> meld [1..4]
[(1,2),(2,3),(3,4)]

Prelude> let meldWith f xs = zipWith f xs (drop 1 xs)
Prelude> meldWith (+) [1..4]
[3,5,7]
```

I think it's time for a vote. I'm partial to pinch or pleat, myself.

Comment: naturally it'll have to be short. So plow is winning there. My question is whether it's important enough to merit a name. What applications does it have that we would use it so often that we wouldn't just use the one-liner zipWith?

Comment: That function is partial and probably should be `let binaryProjection f xs = zipWith f (drop 1 xs) xs`.  The `init` is unnecessary given the use of `zip` and `tail` will error on the empty list where `drop 1` doesn't and provides otherwise matching results.

Comment: I don't know if there is a name for it but I know that I have followed this pattern alot. I would be interested to know if it had a common name. I usually call it a 'merger' because of the way that you are merging values together.

Comment: @Chuck Vose: I (the afore-mentioned compatriot) asked him that same question!  "What are you using it for?"  He said he couldn't remember.  I also built for him a plow function that can pass any number of parameters into the function and it was THEN that he started asking himself how practical this principle is.

Comment: Also, because this question is a little subjective (especially if it does not have a common name already) maybe it should be community wiki?

Comment: @Robert Massaioli: I think the real question is if the function already exists and if we can find it in Hackage or whatever.

Comment: @Ishpeck: I looked in Data.List and could not see anything. Also you can be sure that the function has the type: (a -> a -> b) -> [a] -> [b] and this function is very similar to: http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.1/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.0/Prelude.html#v%3Ascanl

Comment: @lshpeck: A quick [search says no](http://haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%28a+-%3E+a+-%3E+b%29+-%3E+[a]+-%3E+[b]) for the base libs.  It really doesn't belong in the basic libs seeing as its so easily recreated yet not widely used.  I'd also question the value of adding a package dependency for such a small function.  On hackage MissingH or ListLike are the two likely places to find such functionality, but it isn't there.

Comment: I like merge quite well. Anyone know if this name is taken in the greater functional world?

Comment: @Ishpeck - I know I have needed this function a couple different times. I remember distinctly trying to stuff this behavior into a fold and, obviously failing.

Comment: @Legatou: Merge is often used to merge two sorted lists together into one sorted list (See the ListLike package, or it might be in MissingH)

Comment: If you were working with streams instead of specified lists, it could be defined using unfold or scan. But that isn't what the OP is looking for.

Comment: I really don't think it should have a short name -- it's not useful enough for that, and this takes short names away from other uses.

Comment: Stop trying to come up with cute little buzzwords that nobody will understand for obscure, special-purpose operations.  Don't even consider a generic name like "merge".  Use a descriptive phrase, eg. `apply_to_pairs`.

Comment: So I posted this on the Haskell Reddit and they are clever (http://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/dhlso/what_is_or_should_this_function_be_called/): let meld f = map (uncurry f) . (zip `ap` tail)

Comment: A simpler and therefore more readable Python version would be `def plow(f, l): return map(f, l[:-1], l[1:])`

Comment: This reminds me of http://www.cs.cmu.edu/Groups/AI/html/hyperspec/HyperSpec/Body/fun_mapccm_ma_istcm_mapcon.html. Perhaps one of those describes what you are doing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I really can't see any codified names for this anywhere in Python, that's for sure.  "Merge" is good but spoken for in a variety of other contexts.  "Plow" tends to be unused and supplies a great visual of pushing steadily through a line of soil.  Maybe I've just spent too much time gardening.

I also expanded the principle to allow functions that receive any number of parameters.

You might also consider: Pleat.  It describes well the way you're taking a list (like a long strand of fabric) and bunching segments of it together.

```
import operator

def stagger(l, w):
    if len(l)>=w:
        return [tuple(l[0:w])]+stagger(l[1:], w)
    return []

def pleat(f, l, w=2):
    return map(lambda p: f(*p), stagger(l, w))

print pleat(operator.add, range(10))
print pleat(lambda x, y, z: x*y/z, range(3, 13), 3)
print pleat(lambda x: "~%s~"%(x), range(10), 1)
print pleat(lambda a, b, x, y: a+b==x+y, [3, 2, 4, 1, 5, 0, 9, 9, 0], 4)
```

Comment: better to use itertools.starmap instead of `map(lambda p: f(*p)...`

Answer (score 17):

Hmm... a counterpoint.

```
(`ap` tail) . zipWith
```

doesn't deserve a name.

BTW, quicksilver says:

```
 zip`ap`tail
```

The Aztec god of consecutive numbers

Comment: Why wouldn't it?  As counter-counterpoints, `flip mapM`, `foldr (>>) (return ())` and `liftM2 id` *have* been attributed some.  (NB I'm not arguing it should, I'm pointing out the argument is weak)

Comment: map and fold are the two fundamental higher order functions, as a result, uses like this are very common. tail is moderately rare, zip `ap` tail is exceedingly rare. rare + trivial == not a good reason to name.

Comment: I did not know about this though and I think that other people may be in the same boat, irrespective of how long they have used Haskell for. Is there anywhere that goes through a bunch of these useful code snippets, stuff that is not as common as prelude code but common enough to make these posts? Or do most people stumble upon this themselves?

Comment: I have seen this higher-order function used quit often by science graduate students.  Mostly in MatLab and Mathematica and once or twice in python. Knowledge of it was either passed down from whom ever taught them or rediscovered.

Answer (score 6):

Since it's similar to "fold" but doesn't collapse the list into a single value, how about "crease"? If you keep "creasing", you end up "folding" (sort of).

We could go with a cooking metaphor and call it "pinch", like pinching the crust of a pie, though this might suggest a circular zipping, where the last element of the list is paired with the first.

```
def pinch(f, l):
    return map(lambda t: f(*t), zip(l, l[1:]+l[:1]))
```

(If you only like one of "crease" or "pinch", please note so as a comment. Should these be separate suggestions?)

Comment: You can do an "infiniplow" where you can reduce the sequence to a single value by continually "plowing" it. I've called this PlowReduce hitherto. For example, a PlowReduce would plow a sequence [0..9] to the value 2304.

Comment: "Plow" doesn't seem like a good description, since plows turn over, break things up and aerate, none of which seem to apply to what the function does.

Comment: I think pinch is a great candidate!

Answer (score 6):

In Python the `meld` equivalent is in the itertools receipes and called pairwise.

```
from itertools import starmap, izp, tee

def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return izip(a, b)
```

So I would call it:

```
def pairwith(func, seq):
    return starmap(func, pairwise(seq))
```

I think this makes sense because when you call it with the identity function, it simply returns pairs.

Answer (score 5):

Here's another implementation for Python which works if `l` is a generator too

```
import itertools as it

def apply_pairwise(f, l):
    left, right = it.tee(l)
    next(right)
    return it.starmap(f, it.izip(left, right))
```

I think `apply_pairwise` is a better name

Answer (score 3):

This reminds me of *convolution* from image processing. But not sure if this is mathematically correct.

Comment: In image processing images are functions represented as arrays. The example 'binaryProjection (+) [0,1,2,3]' is like convolving a '[1,1]' kernel over a 1D-image (first multiply overlapping coefficients than sum). Though being able to use any other function than '+' makes the higher-order function in question more general.

Comment: This is convolution of a sort.  The two functions convolved  are `f 1 = 1, f 2 = 1` and the function from natural numbers to the input list.  The binary operation is specified by the function argument to `plow` or `meld` or whatever it's called.  Very similar to the DSP sense of convolution of signals where the binop is (+).

Comment: @AaronMcSmooth, no problem.  As @sfty notes, this is an interesting hybrid which is mostly like signal convolution but more general because of the varying binop.  In the more general sense of convolution (rather than the restricted DSP version), this extra generality isn't a difficulty.  Anyway, @sfty noticed it; I didn't on my own.

Answer (score 2):

`zipWithTail` or `adjacentPairs`.

Answer (score 2):

I vote for `smearWith` or `smudgeWith` because it's like you are smearing/smudging the operation across the list.

Answer (score 2):

this seems like ruby's `each_cons`

```
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > (1..10).each_cons(2).to_a

=> [[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5], [5, 6], [6, 7], [7, 8], [8, 9], [9, 10]]
```

Answer (score 2):

The generalized variant of the plain zip version of this is what I would think of as `window`. Not at a ghci terminal right now, but I think `window n = take n . tails`. Then your function is `zipWith (\[x,yj -> f x y) . window 2`. This sort of style naturally works better when f is of type `[a] -> b`.

Answer (score 2):

in C++ Standard Template Library, it is called [adjacent_difference](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/adjacent_difference.html) (though the operator can be any operation, not just subtraction)

Answer (score 1):

<strike>So because there seems to be no name for this I suggest 'merger' or simple 'merge' because you are merging adjacent values together.</strike>

So merge is already taken so I now suggest 'meld' (or 'merger' still but that may be too close to 'merge')

For example:

```
meld :: (a -> a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
meld _ [] = []
meld f xs = zipWith f (init xs) (tail xs)
```

Which can be used as:

```
> meld (+) [1..10]
[3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19]
> meld compare "hello world"
[GT,LT,EQ,LT,GT,LT,GT,LT,GT,GT]
```

Where the second example makes no real sense but makes a cool example.

Comment: I am currently favoring this name. I think it's sufficiently descriptive.

Comment: It's ok but conflicts with `merge :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]` which merges two sorted lists together into one sorted list.

Comment: @TomMD: good point, changing to 'meld' instead. It is not taken, I checked and it is short and descriptive. "Just, meld this list with the (+) function."

Answer (score 1):

Using Mathematica

[Plus](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Plus.html?q=Plus&lang=en) [@@@](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Apply.html#1519920741) [Partition](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Partition.html?q=Partition&lang=en)[{0, 1, 2, 3}, 2, 1]
or either of these more verbose alternatives

```
Apply[Plus, Partition[{0, 1, 2, 3}, 2, 1], {1}]
Map[Apply[Plus, #] &, Partition[{0, 1, 2, 3}, 2, 1]]
```

I have used and enjoyed this higher order function in many languages but I have enjoyed it the most in Mathematica; it seems succinct and flexible broken down into Partition and Apply with levelspec option.

Comment: I must admit Haskell has won me over for the most part 15 months later.

Answer (score 1):

I'd be tempted to call it *contour* as I've used it for "contour" processing in music software - at the time I called it twomap or something silly like that.

There are also two specific named 'contours' in music processing one is gross contour - does the pitch go up or down. The other is refined contour where the the contour is either up, down, leap up or leap down, though I can't seem to find a reference for how large the semitone difference has to be to make a leap.

Answer (score 1):

Nice idiom!  I just needed to use this in Perl to determine the time between sequential events.  Here's what I ended up with.

```
sub pinch(&@) {
  my ( $f, @list ) = @_;
  no strict "refs";

  use vars qw( $a $b );

  my $caller = caller;
  local( *{$caller . "::a"} ) = \my $a;
  local( *{$caller . "::b"} ) = \my $b;

  my @res;
  for ( my $i = 0; $i < @list - 1; ++$i ) {
    $a = $list[$i];
    $b = $list[$i + 1];
    push( @res, $f->() );
  }
  wantarray ? @res : \@res;
}

print join( ",", pinch { $b - $a } qw( 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 ) ), $/;
# ==> 1,1,1,1,1,1
```

The implementation could probably be prettier if I'd made it dependent on **List::Util**, but... meh!

Comment: Congrats, necromancer ;) Oh wait... for the necromancer badge, you need +5 for this answer...

Comment: Yeah, Perl gets ugly fast, sigh!

Answer (score 0):

BinaryOperate or BinaryMerge

Comment: If you're going to confine this to only allowing functions that receive two parameters, "dyadic" would be a better prefix.  But the principle here, using elements in a sequence as parameters, should, in theory, expand to more than just dyadic functions.