# How can I check if the number is divisible by a previous number in the list?

Tags: python, list

So I want to look if the number in the list is divisible by a previous number in the list (except 1) and if so, I want to replace that number by 0 Can someone help please? I'm trying to make a 'Sieve of Eratosthenes' algorithm by myself!

So `L1=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`

```
for i in range(len(L1)):
   for j in range(len(L1)):
        if L1[i]%L1[j]<>0:
            L1[i]= 0
```

And no `L1` should be: `[1,2,3,0,5,0,7,0,0,0]`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I'm sorry, but I find it very hard to figure out what you are asking here. It would help if you included some code to show what you have tried, it'll make it much easier for us to help you. Perhaps you could also take a look at http://whathaveyoutried.com for a great article on how to ask good questions?

Comment: Do you mean any of the previous numbers or the directly previous (i.e. `L1[i-1]`)?

Comment: Are you trying to implement a 'Sieve of Eratosthenes' algorithm? If so you should mention it.

Comment: You should show and example of before and after list like [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] -> [1, 2, 3, 'X', 5, 'X', 7, 'X', 'X'].

Comment: Changing from 'X' to 0 seems like you have not thought this out very well.

Comment: You might want to change the number the largest number that it is found to be divisible by, this will eliminate exceptions and the special case of 1, make a list comprehension possible and simpler.

Comment: What an excellent time for a pleat! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774247/what-do-we-call-this-new-higher-order-function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
L1 = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
for i in range(len(L1)):
   for j in range(i):
       if L1[j] not in (0, 1) and L1[i] % L1[j] == 0:
           L1[i] = 0
           break

>>> print L1
[2, 3, 0, 5, 0, 7, 0, 0]
```

Comment: Can you explain this please?

Comment: You fixed it by adding  "not in (0, 1)".

Comment: I haven't noticed (except 1) first but then added this, sorry

Comment: Do You know that this implemntation of Eratosthenes' algorithm is not the best (i thin is not Eratosthenes' algorithm at all)

Answer (score 1):

```
def test(number, lst):
    for i in lst:
        if i not in (0, 1) and number % i == 0:
            return 0
    return number

data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]   
result = []
for i in range(len(data)):
    result.append(test(data[i], data[0:i]))
# Instead of the result = [] and a for-cycle, it is possible to use list-comprehension. 
# Thanks to dansalmo for the suggestion
result = [test(data[i], data[0:i]) for i in range(len(data))]
```

This works properly. It might be not the shortest or the most efficient code, but I think it is very clear. We call a function test for each element of data and each corresponding part of data, which we need to check for divisors. The function returns the correct value: 0 or the number, which we append to the list of results.

Comment: [test(data[i], data[0:i]) for i in range(len(data))] will work in place of the result = ... and for loop.

Comment: Great suggestion, **dansalmo**, thank you! I'll add this code to the answer.

Comment: You could also show a solution that replaces the number with the highest factor > 1 instead of 0.  That might simplify even further yet provide a usable result.

Comment: I meant lowest factor > 1.  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] -> [1, 2, 3, 2, 5, 3, 7, 2, 3].  The end result will only be primes.

Comment: Ah, yeah, I got that. The question required to replace with 0, so that's what I did. And why would it simplify the solution? You just use 2 instead of 0 in this case.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30145/discussion-between-dansalmo-and-ilya)

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question.. There are probably cool mathematical tricks to make this easier that were missing out on but anyway..

Using `itertools` we can get an iterator that returns all n choose 2 combinations of the numbers, then test each pair of numbers according to your criteria and use `ifilter` to get the ones we want to remove:

```
from itertools import ifilter, combinations
nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
def mod(x):
    if 1 in x: return False
    if not max(x)%min(x): return True
seive = [max(x) for x in ifilter(mod,combinations(nums,2))]
```

This will give you the numbers that are to be set to zero. One you get those you can set them to zero:

```
for num in nums:
    if num in seive:
        nums[nums.index(num)] = 0
```

Or alternatively you can get a list of the remaining numbers:

```
primes = [x for x in nums if x not in seive]
```